# The functor of monoids

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I'm studying this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521283043) on introductory level category theory and I couldn't solve this exercise:

[image]

In the first part I've been thinking about the monoid homomorphisms $F: S\to T$ and regarding of second part I don't know even how to begin.

I need help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A covariant functor $F$ from $\tilde S$ ($S$ viewed as a category) to $\tilde T$ obviously sends the unique object of $\tilde S$ to the unique object of $\tilde T$. It maps "morphisms" in $\tilde S$ (that is, elements of the monoid $S$) to "morphisms" in $\tilde T$, and therefore gives a function $f : S \to T$. Finally, the functor satisfies $F(a \circ b) = F(a) \circ F(b)$ for every pair of morphisms in $\tilde S$; considering that composition is multiplication in $S$ (resp. $T$), it means that $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$. Finally, a covariant functor here is exactly the same thing as a homomorphism of monoids.

For a contravariant functor, things are identical, except that in the end, $f(ab) = f(b) f(a)$. Such a thing is called a [antihomomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihomomorphism) (of monoids).

Comment: Why does this functor satisfy $F(a\circ b)=F(a)\circ F(b)$? thank you for your answer.

Comment: By definition of a functor.

Comment: yes, but we have to prove $F$ is a functor.

Comment: No, in the book's question you're given a functor $\tilde S \to \tilde T$ and you want to say what it is in terms of monoids.

Comment: yes, it's true, you're right.

Comment: So if the later is an Abelian monoid then there is no difference between Contra-variant and Co-variant functor. Right?